# Where is the Content Source Name in the SSP Search Database

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, moss2007enterprisesearch

I need to locate the table that contains the **Content Source Name** (along with the **ContentSourceId**) in the **SSP Search Database** (OR anywhere else that it gets stored in).
I may be able to access this via the SharePoint Object Model, but I want it via the db table access (This is not a good practice according to Microsoft).
We looked in all the tables, the closest table we get is MSSCrawlContent, with no Content Source Name.
The article that came close to solving the problem was [this](http://admincompanion.mindsharp.com/BillBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=2d22afa2-592b-471a-9cd1-4e8de8a2abc0&ID=83)

Anyone has any idea where Content Source Name is getting stored?

BTW - The application that needs to access this information is on the same domain but on a different machine.

Answer (score 1):

Content source name and some other settings are stored in the registry. For example in my server they located at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\12.0\Search\Applications\0fd855c3-777f-4f92-94f6-164b00b29062\Gather\Portal_Content\ContentSources, and name is in ...\ContentSources\0\ContentSourceName.  If you change some settings directly in registry then it requires restarting of the “Office SharePoint Server Search” service.

Comment: I updated the question, I need to access from a different machine on the same domain.

Answer (score -1):

its not a good practice because its location may change with future hotfixes & service packs.   if you can find it via the OM, why do you want to find it in the tables?

also, considering that search is going to go through big changes in future release, I suspect this field is one of the most susceptible to being changed.

jt